# Добавление ArrayLIst в Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

Есть у меня `AlertDialog` в нем раньше располагался `ListView` в который выводилось содержимое ArrayList'a. Для красоты я решил заменить его на  `Recyclerview, Card` и начались проблемы.

В `ArrayList<String> mainListWord` в процессе работы добавляются элементы и они должны попадать в карточки `Recyclerview`. Проблема заключается в том, что либо сразу весь список попадает в одну карточку, либо каждая следующая каточка содержит предыдущие элементы + 1. Например: первая карточка: 1 элемент, вторая карточка: 2 элементы и т.д.

Как реализовать так, что бы при добавлении в массив нового элемента, он помещался в свою отдельную карточку?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/innerText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/press"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Press"
        android:layout_below="@id/innerText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="openDialog"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**recycler_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorCardBack">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorCard">

        <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView_1"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:padding="4dp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text_1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView_1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**stats_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/butClose"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText innerText;
    private Button press, butClose;

    private ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> recyclerViewItem;
    private ArrayList<String> mainListWord;
    private AlertDialog OptionDialog;

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerViewItem =  new ArrayList<>();
        mainListWord =  new ArrayList<>();

        innerText = findViewById(R.id.innerText);
        press = findViewById(R.id.butClose);


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void makeRecyclerList(ArrayList<String> income){
       String[] listWord_lenght = income.toArray(new String[0]);
       String keyWord = (String.join("", listWord_lenght));
        recyclerViewItem.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.star, keyWord));

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void openDialog(View v){
        String word = innerText.getText().toString();
        mainListWord.add(word);
            makeRecyclerList(mainListWord);
        Dialogus();
        innerText.setText("");
    }

    public void Dialogus(){

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.stats_fragment, null, false);
            OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            OptionDialog.setTitle("TestInfo");
                recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerViewItem);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    butClose =  v.findViewById(R.id.butClose);
                        OptionDialog.setView(v);
                        OptionDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            butClose.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            butClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    OptionDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            OptionDialog.show();
            }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> arrayList;

    public static class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {




    public ImageView imageView_1;
    public TextView textview_1;


        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_1);
            textview_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_1);
        }
    }


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> arrayList){
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup, false);
            RecyclerViewViewHolder recyclerViewViewHolder= new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);
            return  recyclerViewViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewViewHolder recyclerViewViewHolder, int position) {
        RecyclerViewItem recyclerViewItem = arrayList.get(position);
            recyclerViewViewHolder.imageView_1.setImageResource(recyclerViewItem.getImageResource());
            recyclerViewViewHolder.textview_1.setText(recyclerViewItem.getText_1());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    
}
```

**RecyclerViewItem.java**

```
package freijer.app.one;

public class RecyclerViewItem {

    private int imageResource;
    private String text_1;

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }
    public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
        public String getText_1() {
            return text_1;
        }
        public void setText_1(String text_1) {
            this.text_1 = text_1;
        }


    public RecyclerViewItem(int imageResource, String text_1) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.text_1 = text_1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем адаптере сразу инициализируйте arrayList

```
private ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

А в конструктор ничего передавать не нужно, можно убрать совсем.
Далее, нужно дописать в адаптер метод для вставки значений в arrayList

```
public void addItems(ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> items) {
    arrayList.clear();
    arrayList.add(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

И далее, в вашей актвити вызываете

```
adapter.addItems(recyclerViewItem);
```